# Change image with if statement

Tags: java

When the program loads, there's already and image for a place holder

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(Path + "Hangman1.jpg");   
JLabel label = new JLabel();
label.setIcon(icon);
```

Now i know how to write an if statement that prints out the body part

```
if (guesses >= 1) System.out.print("HEAD ");
if (guesses >= 2) System.out.print("BODY ");
if (guesses >= 3) System.out.print("LEFT ARM ");
if (guesses >= 4) System.out.print("RIGHT ARM ");
if (guesses >= 5) System.out.print("LEFT LEG ");
if (guesses >= 6) System.out.print("RIGHT LEG ");
```

But instead of using a normal System.out.print i want to call up my images (want the image to change)

Comment: Please clarify.  The images are of each 'body part' as opposed to the entire image adding up to that body part?  The game never allows the number of guesses to go down?  If both those are correct, you might start with the Hangman1 image then simply paint each (single) body part to a `Graphics` instance obtained from the image.  That way, it will build up for each guess.

Answer (score 2):

Some thing like

```
String imageName = null;    

if (guesses >= 1) imageName = "Head.jpg";
if (guesses >= 2) imageName = "Body.jpg";
if (guesses >= 3) imageName = "LeftArm.jpg";
if (guesses >= 4) imageName = "RightArm.jpg";
if (guesses >= 5) imageName = "LeftLeg.jpg";
if (guesses >= 6) imageName = "RightLeg.jpg";

ImageIcon icon = null;
if (imageName != null) {
    icon = new ImageIcon(Path + File.seperator + imageName);
}

label.setIcon(icon);
```

Obviously, each image would need to add on to each other...

**UPDATED**

As PaulBellora has been kind enough to, rightly, point out, the previous example is the simplest code change need to meet the requirements of the OP, but that doesn't mean it's right

```
switch (guesses) {
    case 1:
        imageName = "Head.jpg";
        break;
    case 2:
        imageName = "Body.jpg";
        break;
    case 3:
        imageName = "LeftArm.jpg";
        break;
    case 4:
        imageName = "RightArm.jpg";
        break;
    case 5:
        imageName = "LeftLeg.jpg";
        break;
    case 6:
        imageName = "RightLef.jpg";
        break;
}
```

Would be a slightly better approach.

With a little bit of clever layout management, you could have six labels instead, one for each body part...

```
// Global references to the body parts
public static final ImageIcon RIGHT_LEG_ICON = new ImageIcon(Path + File.seperator + "RightLeg.jpg");
public static final ImageIcon LEFT_LEG_ICON = new ImageIcon(Path + File.seperator + "LeftLeg.jpg");
public static final ImageIcon RIGHT_ARM_ICON = new ImageIcon(Path + File.seperator + "RightArm.jpg");
public static final ImageIcon LEFT_ARM_ICON = new ImageIcon(Path + File.seperator + "LeftArm.jpg");
public static final ImageIcon BODY_ICON = new ImageIcon(Path + File.seperator + "Body.jpg");
public static final ImageIcon HEAD_ICON = new ImageIcon(Path + File.seperator + "Head.jpg");

// Used as fillers to allow the layout manager to maintain the layout
public static final ImageIcon BLANK_LEG_ICON = new ImageIcon(Path + File.seperator + "BlankLeg.jpg");
public static final ImageIcon BLANK_ARM_ICON = new ImageIcon(Path + File.seperator + "BlankArm.jpg");
public static final ImageIcon BLANK_BODY_ICON = new ImageIcon(Path + File.seperator + "BlankBody.jpg");
public static final ImageIcon BLANK_HEAD_ICON = new ImageIcon(Path + File.seperator + "BlanHead.jpg");

...

// Setup the initial state...(probably in the constructor or when the game rests)
rightLegLabel.setIcon(BLANK_LEG_ICON);
leftLegLabel.setIcon(BLANK_LEG_ICON);
rightArmLabel.setIcon(BLANK_ARM_ICON);
leftArmLabel.setIcon(BLANK_ARM_ICON);
bodyLabel.setIcon(BLANK_BODY_ICON);
headLabel.setIcon(BLANK_BODY_ICON);

...

// As the guesses change...
switch (guesses) {
    case 6:
        rightLegLabel.setIcon(RIGHT_LEG_ICON);
    case 5:
        leftLegLabel.setIcon(LEFT_LEG_ICON);
    case 4:
        rightArmLabel.setIcon(RIGHT_ARM_ICON);
    case 3:
        leftArmLabel.setIcon(LEFT_ARM_ICON);
    case 2:
        bodyLabel.setIcon(BODY_ICON);
    case 1:
        headLabel.setIcon(HEAD_ICON);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense - you're just reassigning the same variable.

Comment: How does it not make sense? `if guess is >= 2` you want to use the image for "Body".  You then load the image from the file system and assign it to the label.  Would you prefer to have a `JLabel` per body part?  Taken with JonLin's suggestion, this is the extended version.

Comment: If there have been 3 guesses, `imageName` will be assigned `"Head.jpg"`, then it will be reassigned `"Body.jpg"`, then it will be reassigned `"LeftArm.jpg"`. Then LeftArm.jpg *only* will be loaded and used.

Comment: @PaulBellora personally, I'd have gone with a `switch` statement, but that's me.  This achieves the OP's request in the smallest amount of immediate effort

Comment: @PaulBellora You're points are valid, I've updated the examples with some additional ideas, hopefully, I won't have confused the OP :P

Answer (score 1):

You should create 7 images, each in its own "hangman" state. And load the appropriate image after each failed guess. Replacing the `System.out.print("HEAD ")` calls with the `label.setIcon()` call instead.