# How to set an ImageIcon using a Switch statement

Tags: java, eclipse, image, switch-statement

Alright, I am pretty much brand new at coding, but I am trying.

I need to create an ImageIcon that will use a switch statement to determine which image to show.

I looked at the thread here: [Change image with if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065088/change-image-with-if-statement)

which recommended a switch statement over an if statement, so I thought it would help. But when I edit my code, and change it from what I had before, I get an error that says "ImageIcon cannot be resolved to a variable". I've tried a variety of capitalization combos but none of them are working.I left the code I originally had underneath the first case. That code is not giving me any error messages but I'm thinking I should not be creating a new ImageIcon for each case, since I need to pull from just one in the program and have the switch statement determine which image to display.

Revised Code

```
  public ImageIcon dieImage(String string)
   {
       ImageIcon dieImage = new ImageIcon("");

      switch (faceValue){

       case 1: dieImage = new ImageIcon ("src/1.jpg");
       break;
       case 2: dieImage = new ImageIcon("src/2.jpg");
       break;
       case 3: dieImage = new ImageIcon("src/3.jpg");
       break;
       case 4: dieImage = new ImageIcon("src/4.jpg");
       break;
       case 5: dieImage = new ImageIcon("src/5.jpg");
       break;
       case 6: dieImage = new ImageIcon("src/6.jpg");
       break; 
      }
    return dieImage;
   }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{
   ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("");
}
```

Get rid of the {} and just use:

```
ImageIcon icon;
```

Now your switch statement can assign the proper Icon to be used by your label.

```
//case 1: ImageIcon = ("src/1.jpg");
case 1: icon = new ImageIcon("src/1.jpg");
```

You have invalid syntax, fix the code as shown above.

Your other statement do nothing as well since they just create an Icon but the Icon is not assigned to a variable which can be used. The code should be:

```
//case 2: new ImageIcon("src/2.jpg");
case 2: icon = new ImageIcon("src/2.jpg");
```

Then to use this icon you would need to update the label containing the Icon:

```
label.setIcon( icon );
```

Comment: So, I do have to have a "new" image icon for each case? This is the updated code with your suggestions and the changes Eclipse wanted me to make. There are now no errors,but I am not sure if the return should be "dieImage" or "null.

Comment: @Rachel, Yes you return the Icon. Don't forget to "accept" the answer so people know the problem has been solved.